# Why this multidimensional array isn't received in PHP using Ajax?

Tags: javascript, php, arrays, ajax

I am posting a multidimensional array from JS using Ajax call and I dont received it in PHP:

```
   $.ajax({
    type: 'post',
    url: 'external_submit.php',
    dataType: "json",
    data: {
      edit_rfid_changes_submit: edit_rfid_changes_submit,
      edited_rfid_arr: edited_rfid_arr
   }
```

I am 100% sure I have done this before and it always succeeded, why doesn't work this time is beyond me!

**EDIT:**

this is how I am creating the array:

```
  var edited_rfid_arr = [];
  for (var i = 0; i < input_fields.length; i++) {       
      let obj = [];
      let rfid = input_fields[i].value;
      let id = input_fields[i].attributes['data-rfid_id'].value;
      obj['rfid'] = rfid;
      obj['id'] = id;
      edited_rfid_arr.push(obj);      
  }
```

Comment: Show your PHP code.

Comment: Your value of `edited_rfid_arr` is not valid. In JS, you can only use `key: value` in objects, not arrays. It should be `[{rfid: "45456", id: "69"}, ...`

Comment: In PHP, you should then be able to access them as `$_POST['edited_rfid_arr'][$i]['rfid']` and `$_POST['edited_rfid_arr'][$i]['id']`

Comment: @Barmar pelase check the edited question, I mistakenly typed a wrong format of the array before. Now the question is corrected

Comment: Use `let obj = {}`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should make `obj` a plain object, not an array. Although you can add named properties to arrays (since arrays are just a kind of object), the properties are ignored when jQuery serializes the array.

So change the variable declaration to:

```
let obj = {};
```

Or you could get rid of the `obj` variable entirely, and just do:

```
edited_rfid_arr.push({rfid, id});
```

And you can get rid of the entire loop by using `map()`:

```
var edited_rfid_arr = input_fields.map(field => 
    ({rfid: field.value, id: field.attributes['data-rfid_id'].value}));
```